# Voronoi formula and twists by additive characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I was wondering if there are any references for the error term in the problem
$$\sum_{n\leq x} r(n) \exp(2\pi i\frac{a}{q}n)$$
where $r(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two integer squares
and $a,q$ are coprime positive integers.

The main term should be $c(q) \frac{x}{q}$ for some function $c(q)$ behaving as a constant on average but I am interested in the error term, namely, what are the records for
the values $\epsilon>\frac{1}{4}$ and $\lambda$ in the estimate
$$\sum_{n\leq x} r(n) \exp(2 \pi i \frac{a}{q}n)=c(q) \frac{x}{q}+O\Big(x^\epsilon q^\lambda \Big).$$